# MYSQL error on table creation

Tags: mysql

I am getting an error for the following code:

```
create table JOB_TBL(
JT_JOB_ID_FLD INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
JT_JOB_DESCRIPTION_FLD VARCHAR(4000),
JT_JOB_POSTER_FLD INT NOT NULL,
JT_JOB_POST_DATE_FLD DATE NOT NULL,
JT_JOB_CLOSE_DATE_FLD DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (JT_JOB_ID_FLD),
FOREIGN KEY (JT_JOB_POSTER_FLD)
REFERENCES USER_TBL(UT_USER_ID_FLD)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

At first I thought it had something to do with the NOT NULL on the two date fields, but it is still giving an error when I run the statement without those not nulls.  Here is the error I receive:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FLD INT NOT NULL,
JT_JOB_POST_DATE_FLD DATE NOT NULL,
JT_JOB_CLOSE_DATE_FLD DA' at line 4
```

Comment: `JT_JOB_POSTER_ FLD INT NOT NULL,` --- so you don't see anything wrong here?

Comment: This is part of a huge query I was writing, and microsoft word made the space nearly invisible, thanks

Comment: "and microsoft word made the space nearly invisible" --- O_o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JT_JOB_POSTER_ FLD INT NOT NULL,
              ^----- what's this?
```

Mysql explicitly points you to the wrong place, next time just hold your breath and read it carefully.

Answer (score 2):

There should not be a space between after the underscore in this line:

```
JT_JOB_POSTER_ FLD INT NOT NULL,
             ^^^
```